# Android: ImageSpan in TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

I put an imagespan in a text view and I want to get the contents of the textview (including the images).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you means including the images... imageSpan will not replace the text, if you use the method getText() you still will get the text you set up before(or client set up ), and if you want to show it, just use imageSpan agin, that's it. and my english is not very well... so if you confuse about what i say, i just can say i am sorry about it